# JSON data issue iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting this data from JSON web services

```
[{"identity":"DEMO","assets":[{"identity":"34DL3611","systemId":"544507"},{"identity":"34GF0512","systemId":"5290211"},{"identity":"34HH1734","systemId":"111463609"},{"identity":"34HH1736","systemId":"111463622"},{"identity":"34YCJ15","systemId":"294151155"}],"systemId":4921244}]
```

I am using this method to get the values of assets for identity ("assets":[{"identity":"34DL3611","systemId":"544507"}):

```
 vehicleList = [dict objectForKey: @"assets"];

    self.listVehicles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [vehicleList count]; index++) {

    itemDict = [vehicleList objectAtIndex: index];

    [self.listVehicles addObject:[itemDict objectForKey:@"identity"]];
}
```

how can I get the systemId values ... ?

I have tried this for systemId

```
vehicleListID = [dict objectForKey:@"systemId"];

    self.listVehiclesID =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [vehicleListID count]; index++) {

    assetsIdDict = [vehicleListID objectAtIndex: index];

    [self.listVehiclesID addObject:[assetsIdDict objectForKey:@"systemId"]];
}
```

but getting error: [__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x784c730

Comment: Same way.. `[itemDict objectForKey:@"systemId"]`.. For that to having in array, u need to initialize new NSMutableArray.

Comment: I have tried that but it is giving error:[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x784c730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json response you are getting is an array.  vehicleList should be the objectatIndex 0 of json response.

```
    NSDictionary  *vehicleList = [[arrayLoadedFromJson objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey: @"assets"];


vehicleList = [dict objectForKey: @"assets"];

    self.listVehicles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [vehicleList count]; index++) {

    itemDict = [vehicleList objectAtIndex: index];

    [self.listVehicles addObject:[itemDict objectForKey:@"identity"]];

    [self.listVehicles addObject:[itemDict objectForKey:@"systemId"]];

}
```

This you have to insert:-in your code

```
  [self.listVehicles addObject:[itemDict objectForKey:@"systemId"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're basically almost there. You just want this probably:

```
NSString *systemId = [itemDict objectForKey:@"systemId"];
```

With regard to this code you have:

```
vehicleListID = [dict objectForKey:@"systemId"];

    self.listVehiclesID =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [vehicleListID count]; index++) {

    assetsIdDict = [vehicleListID objectAtIndex: index];

    [self.listVehiclesID addObject:[assetsIdDict objectForKey:@"systemId"]];
}
```

... well that is just totally wrong. That's returning the `NSNumber` which in your example JSON is `4921244` right at the end of the JSON string. You're then calling `count` on it, but it's not an array, so it crashes.

If you want to get all the values out of that JSON you can use this:

```
NSNumber *outerIdentity = [dict objectForKey:@"identity"];
NSNumber *outerSystemId = [dict objectForKey:@"systemId"];
NSArray *vehicleList = [dict objectForKey:@"assets"];
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [vehicleList count]; index++) {
    NSDictionary *itemDict = [vehicleList objectAtIndex: index];
    NSString *identity = [itemDict objectForKey:@"identity"];
    NSString *systemId = [itemDict objectForKey:@"systemId"];
}
```

Then do whatever it is you want to do with all those objects.

Answer (score 0):

For that to having in separate array, you need to initialize new NSMutableArray and add the objects.

Else, the better way is, declare a new class with 2 NSString members say, `identity` and `systemId`. Extract the values from JSON and assign to the class members. And add that object to the array.