# Parsing values from NSArray based on JSON format

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsmutablearray

I have a NSArray which is based on JSON format. I requested it from the web and saved it in the array. I am trying to use a dictionary to get the values of "categoryname" and "subscore" and store them in new arrays, but they remain empty. Do I have to convert the array back to NSData using JSON serialisation or is there a more direct way to achieve this?

**NSArray detailedscore:**

```
    {
      "articles": [
        {
          "abstract": "text",  
          "title": "title"
        }
      ], 
      "subscore": 3, 
      "categoryname": "Reporting"
    }, 
    {
      "articles": [
        {
          "abstract": "text2",  
          "title": "title"
        }
      ], 
      "subscore": 1, 
      "categoryname": "Power"
    }]
}
```

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [self.detailedscore count]; i++)
    {


        NSMutableDictionary * dc = [self.detailedscore objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString * score = [dc objectForKey:@"subscore"];
        NSString * categoryname = [dc objectForKey:@"categoryname"];

        [self.allscores addObject:subscore];
        [self.allcategories addObject:categoryname];

        for (NSString *yourVar in allcategories) {

            NSLog (@"Your Array elements are = %@", yourVar);


        }
```

Comment: detailedscore is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: I take it from the web and store it as a transformable attribute in core data then I grab it as NSArray. My question is how I can process it from this point

Comment: I would refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850587/json-data-issue-iphone

Comment: How about posting a valid piece of JSON in your question?  "How do I parse JSON?" questions get asked nearly daily here...so there is not a lot of tolerance.

Comment: @borrrden I have searched similar problems. Other than some external libraries I haven't found anything. And I don't see anyone here answering it either.

Comment: Parsing JSON is really not complicated.  The library is not the problem.  Furthermore, the JSON you posted in your question is invalid so how can you expect anyone to answer it accurately?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the array use below code
for(int i = 0; i < [self.detailedscore count]; i++)
    {

```
    NSMutableDictionary * dc = [self.detailedscore objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString * score = [dc objectForKey:@"subscore"];
    NSString * categoryname = [dc objectForKey:@"categoryname"];

    [self.allscores score];
    [self.allcategories addObject:categoryname];

    for (NSString *yourVar in allcategories) {

        NSLog (@"Your Array elements are = %@", yourVar);


    }
```

Comment: I am sorry I put the wrong content of the array. I fixed it. I don't need to get score_detailed. I already have it stored in the array. I need to get all the subscores and categories of it without having to go back to the web service requests

Comment: How is this different from what I did?

Comment: you are using score as key instead of subscore. also in the array you have to score var containing string.

Comment: Its just a typo. I am printing the category names anyway

Answer (score 0):

{} ----> means dictionary, []---> array..... this is a rule I follow while assinging the return value from webservices as NSArray or NSDictionary....
Depending on your current JSON format, perhaps this might give you an idea

```
NSMutableArray *categoryArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *childDict in self.detailedscore)
{
    [categoryArray addObject:[childDict objectForkey:@"categoryname"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't in the array or dictionary or the web request. I didn't allocated the NSMutableArrays so they were empty all the time. The code works fine for extracting values from the array in case anyone wants to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError) {
            NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&connectionError];
            NSLog(@"Dict %@",dict);
            BOOL isValid = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict];
            if (isValid) {
                [target getJSONFromresponseDictionary:dict forConnection:strTag error:connectionError];
            }
            else{
                NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [target getStringFromresponseDictionary:strResponse forConnection:strTag error:error];
            }

Comment: No explanation?  No formatting? Copy-pasted Unrelated content?